# Access OWIN Self-Hosted Web API Controller from Test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, owin

I am trying to write an integration test that tests a service that makes an HTTP request to a 3rd party service.  I've created a mock 3rd party service by self hosting a dummy controller with the same end point using OWIN.  I need to Assert the content of the HTTP request to the mocked 3rd party service by accessing it from within the controller method.  However, since OWIN creates the instance of the controller for me, I don't have access to that instance.  I tried using a static property on the controller that gets updated with the controller method gets hit, which sort of worked, but I'm getting timing issues with multiple tests running at once.

Any ideas how I can either provide a specific controller instance to OWIN or how I can access the data to Assert directly in the controller method?

Comment: please provide a [mcve] of what you done so far